# Is there a way to look at the full request object in AWS Xray

Tags: aws-xray

I have a nodejs project where I am receiving a lot of http 400 error. I have aws xray implemented. Where in xray can I see the full request object with the full http header information? Does aws xray show this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add arbitrary JSON data to X-Ray segments and subsegments as metadata. This will be viewable in the X-Ray console by viewing the problematic segment's details and clicking on the "Metadata" tab as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console.html#xray-console-segments

For documentation on how to add metadata with the Node SDK: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-nodejs-segment.html#xray-sdk-nodejs-segment-metadata